# Javascript - set all keys of a Map object to a value

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```
const myMap = new Map()

myMap.set("banana", true)
myMap.set("apple", true)

Object.keys(myMap).forEach(key => {myMap.set(key, false)})

console.log(myMap.get("banana")) // returns true should return false
console.log(myMap.get("apple")) // returns true should return false
```

I want to set all the values of this `Map` to `false`, but it doesn't work at all.

I've tried something like this:

```
Object.keys(myMap).forEach(key => myMap[key] = false)
```

but this doesn't work either.

Is there a way to *fill* all keys of a `Map` to a specific *value*?

Comment: Try logging the thing you're looping through `console.log(Object.keys(myMap))` and see if it's what you expect or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specifically call `Map.set` in order to set a value in a Map. `myMap[key] = value` will only work for *plain objects*. You should also use `myMap.keys()` to get an iterator of the map's keys:

```js
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set("banana", true);
myMap.set("apple", true);

[...myMap.keys()].forEach((key) => {
  myMap.set(key, false);
});

console.log(myMap.get("banana"));
console.log(myMap.get("apple"));
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you `spread` the keys inside an array and then use the `.forEach()` of array prototype?

Comment: `forEach` requires defining a `value` argument, which goes unused, which seems ugly IMO. Since only the keys are needed, the `.keys()` method seemed appropriate, but unfortunately it returns an iterator, not an array, so I can't `forEach` over it directly. Could have used `for..of` to avoid the spreading, but I [prefer array methods](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators-and-generators) over `for` when possible. (I really wish `.keys()` and other methods returned arrays instead of iterators, it would make code look nicer)

Comment: Yea, `keys()` and `entries()`, both of they returns iterators and feels a bit like out of consistency to the similar methods available for `objects`. I see what you mean. Anyway, thanks for clarify my question, I was just curious.

Answer (score 7):

A [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) has a [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) method for traverse it, that you can use in this particular case:

```js
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set("banana", true);
myMap.set("apple", true);

myMap.forEach((value, key, map) => map.set(key, false));

console.log(
  "Banana:", myMap.get("banana"),
  "Apple:", myMap.get("apple")
);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

The documentation of the callback invoked on each element, from `MDN`, says:

> The `forEach` method executes the provided `callback` once for each key of the map which actually exist. It is not invoked for keys which have been deleted. However, it is executed for values which are present but have the value undefined. The `callback` is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element `value`
> - the element `key`
> - the `Map` object being traversed

Comment: This is a very good answer, too. I felt [CertainPerformance's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885596/2924072) answer a little bit more succinct, but I also respect this answer and it does work!

Comment: I just realized that your answer is just as good. If I were to use this code:
`myMap.forEach((_,key) => { myMap.set(key, false) })`. Which one is more efficient you think?

Comment: @Student22 If you are speaking about comparison with spreading to create a new array, then I believe there will be no notable difference, unless you have an array with huge quantity of elements (maybe millions), in that case I will go with what you have wrote.